# Custom configmap for nginx ingress controller installed with gitlab managed apps

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, nginx-ingress

I have a nginx ingress controller installed via gitlab managed apps.

I would like to disable hsts for subdomains. I known I can disable it via a custom ConfigMap (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/)

But I don't know where to place this and how to name it so the gitlab ingress will pick it up.

Comment: Please beware that there are two NGINX controllers. First from the Nginx themselves and second from the Kubernetes SIGs.

Comment: Yes Thank You :-) If I'm not completely wrong the one installed by gitlab is: nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io so https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/15c2d59e0fbb6508f36d70239e4c26fafd99965c/cmd/nginx/flags.go#L65 ConfigMap name is passed by a cmd flag to the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I did in the end is using: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/applications.html#install-using-gitlab-cicd.

So the gitlab-managed-apps are not managed via ui but with a "cluster management project".
So now I don't have to figure out how to place that config map in my cluster (and how to name it) but I can just configure the ingress controller (and everything else) via the helm chart with a simple values.yaml.

I just cloned the https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/example-cluster-applications/ example and added:

```yaml
# .gitlab/managed-apps/ingress/values.yml
controller:
  replicaCount: 1
  config:
    hsts-include-subdomains: "false"
```

So this is still an alpha feature but for now it works well for me :-)